# How to force DllMain to return true while having a loop?

Tags: c++, dll, return, infinite-loop

I am writing a dll and face this problem. While its working as intented, it never reaches to the point of return true, so the injector hangs.
Here is the code:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(0, "all ok", "injection ok", 0);
        while(true){
            ..................}
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

So, is there any way to return true even though I have to use an infinite loop?

Comment: By definition, an *infinite loop* never ends, so you can't *return* from it. Think about it. If you return, you're not in an infinite loop, and if you''re in an infinite loop you don't want to return. You don't do loops in DLLMain(). You use the absolute minimum code you need and then return.

Comment: Don't put code in DllMain.  It's holding a loader lock. See the warning here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If this is being injected use CreateRemoteThread and put your logic in the called function, you should never call anything from user32.dll (including MessageBox) from DllMain anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to return when you has a infinite loop. Why do you need to return ? 
you can use DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH to know when to exit.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a VOID routine (VOID meaning no return value) which you can invoke from your DllMain routine. The VOID routine will create a new thread and the thread will point to another routine which will handle execution of your main code-base. Meanwhile, you return back from DllMain and the new thread doesn't hold you up because you're on a different thread.

Whether you stay in DllMain or not is irrelevant, unless you switch threads to handle your infinite loop, the thread will be blocked from reaching the return point.

You can do this effortlessly with the documented CreateThread routine from the Win32 API. Thank me later.